# Monitoring and re-establishing a PostgreSQL connection

Tags: ruby, multithreading, error-handling, postgresql

Within a complicated Ruby project, I need to monitor the connection to a PostgreSQL database, as answered [here](//stackoverflow.com/questions/29655721/postgres-libpq-how-to-tell-if-a-connection-has-been-terminated). I use a thread for this purpose. Every few milliseconds, I invoke "consume_input" which will raise an exception of the database connection no longer exists. If might have been closed for a number of reasons, but there is no indication from the socket/connection why it is closed. If the server is restarted and is alive again within a certain time-frame, I reconnect and assume everything is fine. Otherwise, I notify another object via a callback that all is not well, and the thread exits normally.

I'm looking for tips and suggestions on following best practices and correctness. I need some general Ruby advice on making my code cleaner and more robust.

```
PG_MAX_FAILURES=10
PG_SLEEP_QUANTA=0.25
def monitor_start
  log.info("db: #{__method__}")
  _dbconn=nil
  if @monitor.alive?
    @monitor.kill
    sleep PG_SLEEP_QUANTA
  end
  @monitor = Thread.new {
    _failures=0
    while true do
        begin
          if ! _dbconn.is_a?PG::Connection or _dbconn.status() != PG::CONNECTION_OK
            log.info("Reconnecting...")
            _dbconn = PG.connect( @dbconnstr )
            log.info("Reconnected.")
          else
            _dbconn.consume_input()
            _failures=0
          end
          sleep PG_SLEEP_QUANTA
        rescue PG::ConnectionBad => ex
          _failures += 1
          if _failures >= PG_MAX_FAILURES
            @monitor_post_callback.call()
            break # Thread.current.stop ??
          end
          log.warn("Postgresql connection lost. Retry# #{_failures}...")
          sleep PG_SLEEP_QUANTA
          retry
        rescue => ex
          log.warn("Other exception #{ex.class} #{ex.message}")
        end
    end
  }
end
```

Answer (score 2):

What follows is just my subjective opinion; you can disagree.

1. Robust code is maintainable.  You need to be able to change this code if you find a bug in it, or if the requirements change. It might even be that *someone else* may need to maintain this code.  So you should probably use a regular indenting pattern (2 spaces is normal for Ruby). That would make it a lot easier to see what was going on.
2. Likewise, your code would be cleaner if it was split into separate functions. Making the contents of the `thread.new` block a separate function would be a good place to start, but you could (and maybe should) go further than that.
3. It seems to me that the `sleep ... retry` at the end of the first rescue block are redundant, since you are going to loop around again anyway. YMMV.

Comment: If the read fails, there is no other point where `sleep` is called. But I see your point that `retry` is technically redundant.  Two-space indentation noted, thank you.

Comment: Can't split into two functions here. The code preceding the Thread is to make sure that multiple instances of the thread aren't run concurrently.

Comment: `@monitor = Thread.new { thread_body_function }` ?

Comment: Hrm, that might make unit-testing easier.

Comment: Exactly. The more you break the code up, the easier it is to read (and therefore maintain) and the easier it is to test.  And if you pass _dbconn into thread_body_function it gets even better: dependancy injection makes the tests even easier (mocks & stubs) plus it makes it easier to break the code up further.